# My scrpay text results keep returning " \n \n"

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

I try to scrape some search results from

> https://www.companiesintheuk.co.uk/Company/Find?q=a

With the commands

```
response.css('div.search_result_title').extract()
```

Which works, but as I try to remove the html tags with

```
response.css('div.search_result_title::text').extract()
```

But I keep getting, \n\n\n\n\n\n\n

> [u'\n', u'\n(Dissolved)\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n', u'\n']
>
> > > 

Do you guys know why? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get the headers' texts? You have `a` inside `div`, so yes, you get a lot of empty data. Use `div.search_result_title a::text`.

Comment: I didnt notice.. how careless.. thank you very much! You thought me a valueble lesson!!

Comment: Also, Do you happen to know how to just get the div class class="searchResult"
So, showing the names,adresses together? with the text only?

Comment: Try `response.css('div.searchResult ::text')`, for example. This will extract whole the texts inside tags of `div.searchResult` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to get the headers' texts? You have `a` inside `div`, so yes, you get a lot of empty data. Use `div.search_result_title a::text`.

And for second question about get whole block's text:

```
for i in response.css('div.searchResult'): 
    print ' '.join([j.strip() for j in i.css('::text').extract() if j.strip()])
```

Comment: Thank you very much i am getting the results I wanted! If I want to yield the results for future output, do i just replace teh print statement with a keyword to yield?

Comment: Not exactly. Instead of print do `yield {'data': ' '.join([j.strip() for j in i.css('::text').extract() if j.strip()])}`

Comment: Thank you again for helping me out! Have a great day!